# creating a plnkr with external libraries

Tags: angularjs, plunker, plnkr.co

I am having issues with `angular-utils-pagination` directive in my application. I want to create a plnkr with my implementation so that I can post it here. I am not able to search for this library in plnkr. Any idea on how to import this in plnkr.
Please let me know how to import the javascript file in my plnkr.

Comment: Click New file -> copy paste your library code there.

Comment: Thanks. why is it down voted? I am new to plnkr and hence posted this question.

Comment: Posting it as answer, so that it would be helpful for newbie like you. May be people are thinking you didn't do enough research on your question

Answer (score 0):

Click `New file` -> copy paste your library code there.

Comment: I do not se e `New File` option. There is `New project` option. May be in 2015, it used to be present. Not any more. I am searching for the same answer now.